# Swift Package Manager - Bridging Header, File Not Found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

I want to migrate my CocoaPods to Swift Package Manager.

I'm getting the following error if I add Objective c Framework using SwiftPM

```
'RSKImageCropper/RSKImageCropper.h' file not found
```

[image]

[image]

If I install the framework using pods, everything runs fine.

```
pod 'RSKImageCropper', '~> 3.0.2'
```

What should i do to solve this error?

Comment: if you look in the framework itself, does it have that header? Does Xcode offer to autocomplete it for you?

Comment: Yes, see in image. Xcode doesn't offer to autocomplete

Comment: Have you found the answer for this yet? @phnmnn

Comment: yes, see answer below

Answer (score 4):

Package.swift of RSKImageCropper

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RSKImageCropper",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v9)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "RSKImageCropper",
            targets: ["RSKImageCropper"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "RSKImageCropper",
            path: "RSKImageCropper",
            resources: [
                .copy("RSKImageCropperStrings.bundle")
            ],
            publicHeadersPath: "include"
        ),
    ]
)
```

Only headers in include folder is public and visible (publicHeadersPath key).
Fixed by changing

```
#import <RSKImageCropper/RSKImageCropper.h>
```

to

```
#import <RSKImageCropper/RSKImageCropViewController.h>
```